# Separation of concerns in reducers working in same action

Tags: javascript, redux

I have the following normalized state shape that I want to implement.

```
{
    userAccounts: {
        byId: {
            "1234": {
                "id": "1234",
                "name": "Obi-wan",
                "gender": "Male",
                "age": 40
            },
            "4321": {
                "id": "4321",
                "name": "Padme",
                "gender": "Female",
                "age": 26
            },
            ...
        },
        allIds: ["1234", "4321", ...]
    }
}
```

This is the action that fetches data to get user accounts.

```
export const getAccounts = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: GET_ACCOUNTS_REQUEST});
    return API.getAccountsList(session).then(
      (response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ACCOUNTS_SUCCESS,
          payload: response
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        ...
      }
    )
  };
};
```

The payload contains a key called accounts and this key contains an array among other non relevant fields.

```
payload: {
  accounts: [ { ... }, { ... } ],
  ...
}
```

My reducer waits for the action GET_ACCOUNTS_SUCCESS and I use combineReducers.

```
[GET_USERS_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
    return combineReducers({
      byId,
      allIds
    });
}
```

My current implementation of the reducer is like this:

```
const byId = (state, action) => {
  const { accounts } =  action.payload;
  const nextState = {
    byId: {},
    allIds: []
  };
  accounts.map(account => {
    nextState.byId[account.id] = {
      ...account
    };
    nextState.allIds = [
      ...nextState.allIds,
      account.id
    ]
  });
  return nextState;
};
```

I would like to separate this reducers into two to have better separation of concerns avoiding to do two maps.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could create two new reducers listening to two new actions `SET_ACCOUNT_BY_ID` and `SET_ACCOUNT_BY_ALL_IDS` (as an example) which are dispatched by the `GET_ACCOUNTS_SUCCESS` action. When dispatching these two actions, you can pass in only the required data to them.

Comment: The solution that you propose would produce two renders and I would like to avoid it if possible. I'm more interested in improving the quality of the byId reducer keeping just only one action type.

Comment: Another approach would be to have 2 separate functions operating on the different parts of the payload and call it from the reducer. This will move the logic out of the reducer into functions which can be individually tested.